# Calling child view controller of navigation controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, swift4

All,

I have a main home controller with - Tab bar at bottom and container view remaining screen.
Container view will keep replacing view controllers when each tab is clicked.

Each tab has view controllers - embedded in their individual navigation controllers.

I have a scenario where, on receiving push notification, I need to open a view controller(level 2) inside a navigation controller.

Can anyone let me know how to instantiate that view controller the is nested inside the navigation controller

[image]

Like in the picture above, I need to open the detail view and also show the navigation bar on top and tab bar in bottom when opened from app delegate

Comment: you need your tab bar controller to select the appropriate child VC and call a function on ZVXC1 to show the detail view; alternatively you could manipulate the `viewControllers` array of ZVCX1's navigation controller directly. You would still need the tab bar controller to do the right thing.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not using TabBarcontroller for a reason.  On initial loading , I need to show home screen, with tab bar at bottom. But, this home screen ins not part of tabs. It will be shown only once.

Comment: Ok, but the process is still effectively the same; The view controller that is managing the child views (The one that *looks like* a tab controller in your image) needs to set the correct child navigation controller than you either need to push the right set of view controllers onto that navigation controller or manipulate its `viewControllers` array directly